# PHP - Remove line from html response that contains matching string(s)

Tags: php, html

Say I have a HTML response of:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <div>
      <!-- some content -->
   </div>
</html>
```

How would I remove the lines containing `<head>` and `</head>`?

I know a method of replacing the string occurrences with blanks:

```
$mtHtml = // my returned html

$filtered = preg_replace('/<head>|<\/head>/', '', $myHtml);
```

However, this just leaves blank lines...

```
<html>
  

   <div>
...
```

Is there any way in which I can remove the lines completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the job for you: `/\n\s*(<head>|<\/head>)/g`

As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/UyZoyl/1). Explanation is also available on that link.

Comment: Awesome stuff @André! Regex is always a pain for me. I had looked for things like this for the past couple of days, didn't realise it was the way forward!